# scanf with ^ operator

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    char msg[10];
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    scanf("%[^\n]s",msg);
    printf("%s\n",msg);
    return 0;
}
```

The program is accepting the integer value and printing it, but the second `scanf()` call is not accepting anything. Why is this?

What effect does ^\n on scanf statement in the context.

Comment: `%[^\n]` is a "thing" in itself, you don't need to use the `s` after it. The s is probably being considered literal, by the way, and that will affect your scan.

Answer (score 2):

If the console looks something like this:

```
123
abc
```

Then `stdin` will have the contents: `123\nabc\n`

After a `scanf` call with a `"%d"` format string, `stdin` will now be: `\nabc\n`. Note that the `\n` hasn't been consumed.

The specifier `%[^\n]` (the `s` shouldn't be there, that'll just be treated as an extra character to consume immediately after) means *read every character until a `\n`*, so since there are no characters before the `\n` at the start of the string nothing will be stored into the buffer, and `stdin` will remain as: `\nabc\n`.

To fix this, change the first `scanf` format string to `"%d\n"`, so that after a number is read the `\n` will be consumed. Since `%[^\n]` also won't consume the `\n`, you might want to also change that format string to `"%[^\n]\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the first scanf to:

```
scanf("%d\n",&a);
```

Otherwise the second scanf just sees the \n and reads 0 items (and thus leaves your msg unchanged.

With your original code, and some added diagnostics:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
  int a;
  int itemsScanned;
  char msg[10]; strcpy (msg, "unchanged");
  itemsScanned=scanf("%d",&a);
  printf("itemsScanned=%d a=%d\n",itemsScanned, a);
  itemsScanned=scanf("%[^\n]s",msg);
  printf("itemsScanned=%d msg=%s\n",itemsScanned, msg);
  return 0;
}
```

The output (when entered 3<\nl) is:

```
> ./a.out
3
itemsScanned=1 a=3
itemsScanned=0 msg=unchanged
```

with the additional \n in the first scanf, and entering 5\nlHugo\nl:

```
./a.out
5
Hugo
itemsScanned=1 a=5
itemsScanned=1 msg=Hugo
```

Comment: i want to know why this is happening

Comment: Because your first scanf leaves the \n in the "buffer". Then the next scanf applies your format-string and just finds the \n, so it can't read anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", msg);
```

This is probably not what you want, you don't need the `s` after the scanset. Doing this you tell `scanf` to look for a `s` character.